# Unable to generate signed APK for release build variant with newly created JKS file

Tags: android, build.gradle, keytool, jks

I'm trying to create new app out of existing code by changing the application ID in build.gradle.

As per my understanding, applicationId is the unique identity for an app. So, if I change the applicationId, it should be treated as a whole new app.

In order to generate a signed build, I should create new JKS file, upload key and passwords. Even though I create them correctly by following [these](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) steps, Android studio fails to generate signed build with below error:

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key new_key from store "C:\Users\Dev\Downloads\test.jks": Invalid keystore format

NOTE: If I use the previous JKS file, alias key and passwords (used for signing the old app which has different applicationId) for signing the APK with new applicationId, I'm able to generate signed APK!

My question is, if applicationId is changed in build.gradle, why android studio is expecting me to use the JKS file and keys of previous app with different applicationId? It should sign the APK with newly created JKS right?

Tried invalidating the cache, clean and rebuild project. But it is not working.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance!